# How to set up the Timeslot API for AES-CCM peripheral use

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I am using a nordic BLE SOC: nrf52 dk, along with s130 and sdk 14.2.0
I want to secure an advertised BLE packet with AES CCM encryption.
The board contains a co-processor for AES calculation that is not accessible while using the soft device that I am using to generate packets and advertise.

The solution is to use timeslot API but I do not know how to do it. There is [a tutorial](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/software-development-kit/posts/setting-up-the-timeslot-api) but it's only valid for nRF5 SDK 11.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without knowing what part of the implementation you're unable to accomplish there'll unlikely be anyone able to help you.

Comment: I will edit the question and specify exactly what was the problem in implementation, I have the answer already and I posted a link but think this might help the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this question in nordic devzone and I got this answer:

> https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/48518/softdevice-handler-h-is-missing
>   The same question has been answered before so I am posting the other answer as well, as it has longer discussion:
>   https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/48025/not-finding-softdevice_handler-h-in-nrf52_sdk_15-0-3